# React Native Can't find variable

Tags: react-native

I'm following along with a lab from school and this just doesn't match up with the results the teacher is getting. I keep getting "Render error Can't find variable sendMessageWithSMS". I'm trying to get it to set off an alert when I "send" an SMS.
I'm trying to call the function but it doesn't seem to know it's a function.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Alert, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import * as MailComposer from 'expo-mail-composer';
import * as SMS from 'expo-sms';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';


function SMSScreen({navigation}) {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState();

  const NumberInputHandler = (value) => {
    setPhoneNumber(value);
  }

  const MessageInputHandler = (value) => {
    setMessage(value);
  }

  sendMessageWithSMS = async () => {
    const isAvailable = await SMS.isAvailableAsync();
    if(isAvailable) {
      const { result } = await SMS.sendSMSAsync(
        [phoneNumber, '1231231234'],
        message
      );
      console.log(result);
      Alert.alert('Message Sent Successfully!')
    } else {
      Alert.alert('SMS Not Available')
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>Send an Email</Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder='Phone Number' onChangeText={NumberInputHandler} />
      <TextInput style={styles.message} placeholder='Message' onChangeText={MessageInputHandler} />
      <Button style={styles.button} title="Send Via SMS" onPress={sendMessageWithSMS} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Add `const` before `sendMessageWithSMS` like you did with the two previous functions.

Comment: Thank you that worked he didn't do that so I had left it out as well

Comment: Have you tried `this.sendMessageWithSMS`?

Answer (score 0):

add `const` before function or `this.functionname()` write while using `onPress`